# Extracting one row from a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, neural-network, numpy-ndarray

I currently testing a NN implementation, in which the train data is stored in numpy matrix.

```
print train_set_data_vstacked_normalized.shape

(219970,400)
```

The input data currently looks like this, i have to feed each row to my neural network ..

It takes in input of shape (none,400).

How do i take one row out, such that the array i take out of the matrix has 400 entries, or 400 columns and one row?

I've tried

```
print train_set_data_vstacked_normalized[:,0].shape
(219970,)

print train_set_data_vstacked_normalized[0,:].shape
(400,)
```

Comment: How is `train_set_data_vstacked_normalized[0,:].reshape(1,400)`?

Comment: Try something like  `x[None, :, 0]` or `x[:,0][None,:]` or `x[:,0].reshape(1,-1)`.

Comment: ...? i am not  sure i understand what that would do.. The data is already structured correctly, and I would want to pass data that just fits the shape.  
I would like to pass the right data..

Comment: @hpaulj error: `Exception: Error when checking : expected dense_input_1 to have shape (None, 400) but got array with shape (1, 219970)`

Comment: Did you try `[None, 0, :]`?  Do you understand what is happening?

Comment: Well... @Abdou post worked.

Comment: Get into an interactive numpy session and experiment with some small arrays.  Don't don't just plug things into a big script.  Experiment/play.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple `for` loop to go through all the rows of the array.

```
nrows = train_set_data_vstacked_normalized.shape
for i in range(nrows[0]):
    row = train_set_data_vstacked_normalized[i, :]

    # now change shape to (1, 400)
    resized_row = row[np.newaxis]

   # now, "resized_row" shape is (1, 400)
   # pass "resized_row" to NN input layer.
   # ...
```

PS: As a side note, just want to remind you that having ~`220K x 400` array in memory takes around  *670 Mb* in my machine. Consider having this as an HDF5 file.